# TStringList and SaveToFile:  How can I tell to go a new line when string is finished?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using `TStringList` and `SaveToFile`. How can I tell to go a new line when string is finished?
In general all strings contained in `TStringList` are saved in one line only. How can I tell the list to put a carriage return when finish string and need to put other string in a new line?

String is format as:

```
'my text....' + #10#13
```

Comment: Add 2 strings to a string list and SaveToFile will emit a file with one line per string. I dispute the premise of your question.

Comment: The newline sequence is `#13#10`.

Comment: @andreas it's sLineBreak in this x-platform era

Comment: @David: I'm still in the Win32 era...

Comment: sLineBreak has been about for a long time, presumably since the first attempt at X-Platform (Kylix)

Comment: @Gerry: It was introduced in Delphi 6, IIRC, along with `CLX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing the strings like you've shown above with `'my text....' + #10#13 + 'other text...'`, your problem is that you have your line  ending characters reversed. On Windows, they should be `#13#10` (or simply use the  `sLineBreak` constant).

Here's a quick app (Delphi XE2) that demonstrates that the bad order of the pair will cause the problem, and a way to fix it:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Add('This is a test string' + #10#13 + 'This is another test string');
    SL.SaveToFile('C:\Test\BadLFPair.txt');

    SL.Clear;
    SL.Add('This is a test string'+ #13#10 + 'This is another test string');
    SL.SaveToFile('C:\Test\BadLFPairFix.txt');
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end.
```

The first, when opened in Notepad, produces:

```
This is a test stringThis is another test string
```

The second:

```
This is a test string
This is another test string
```

Answer (score 4):

You could add (or insert) an empty line:

```
MyStringList.Add('');
MyStringList.SaveToFile(...);
```